# Wildfly unwanted eager EJB Injection

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, wildfly, weld

i am transforming a Java EE application from Weblogic 12.2.1.3 to Wildfly 18.1 (need to stick to Java 1.8) and i am facing a problem with "Eager" EJB injection.

For example, in the deployment of war named **MyWar** that contains a ViewScopedBean:

```
@ViewScoped
public class BatchCCBean implements Serializable {

    @EJB(lookup = "java:global/consumer.batch.common/BatchJobService!com.company.api.batch.RemoteBatchJobService")
    RemoteBatchJobService batchJobService;
}
```

In Weblogic, if consumer.batch.common is NOT deployed during MyWar deployment, everything goes OK, deployment succeeds. If and only IF you try to initialize the BatchCCBean then you get an Exception. In other words it uses *lazy* EJB initialization.

BUT in Wildfly, I cannot deploy the MyWar application without deploying ***consumer.batch.common***  first because Weld in Wildfly 18.1 tries to eagerly initialize all Remote EJB injections during deployment time.

This is not a wanted behavior. Does anybody know how to "disable eager Remote EJB Injection" in Wildfly?

Thanks

Comment: Anyone here please?

Comment: Maybe Weld has a property that you can override when starting the server or in beans.xml?